# awk not doing a new line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

I'm trying to print out the users who are currently logged in (each logged in user of each terminal). This is what I currently have:

```
NOWDATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
NOWTIME=$(date +"%T")
USERS=$(who | awk -v nd="$NOWDATE"_"$NOWTIME" '{printf nd "\n" " User: "$1" Terminal: "$2" Login: "$3" "$4 "\n"}')
```

Unfortunately, `\n` does not work, which means that I can't get a newline after the variable `$4`. The output doesn't do any new lines. How can I achieve that `printf` does a new line after the variable `$4`?

Note: I just perform an echo to list the users, so `echo $USERS`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
echo $USERS
```

with:

```
echo "$USERS"
```

On unquoted variables, such as in `echo $USERS`, the shell performs *word splitting*.  That means that all white space characters, such as newline, are replaced by the first character in IFS (by default: a space).  If you want to keep your newlines, use double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to linux, so I didn't know that. Perfect answer, it's working fine now :)